# How to make page load javascript first, then only load php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, raphael

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function run()
{
  var paper = Raphael( $('.wrapper')[0], 600, 600 ),

       path = paper.path( Raphael.transformPath(pdefs[useDef].path, pdefs[useDef].transform) )
                   .attr( 'stroke-width', 10 )
                   .attr( 'stroke', 'rgb(80,80,80)' ),

    $shim = $('<div id=\'shim-1\'><img src=images/buttons/photo.png></div>') //How to use php assign this line?
}

$(function() {
    run();
});
</script>
```

I want to use php to write a line of code above :  `$shim = $('<div id=\'shim-1\'><img src=images/buttons/photo.png width=75px height=75px></div>')`. Can I write code like below ? :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function run()
    {
      var paper = Raphael( $('.wrapper')[0], 600, 600 ),

           path = paper.path( Raphael.transformPath(pdefs[useDef].path, pdefs[useDef].transform) )
                       .attr( 'stroke-width', 10 )
                       .attr( 'stroke', 'rgb(80,80,80)' ),
    </script>

    <?php
     Use mysql get data from database...
     if (condition) {
    ?>
     <script type="text/javascript"> $shim = $('<div id=\'shim-1\'><img src=images/buttons/photo.png width=75px height=75px></div>') </script>
    <?php
     }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    }

    $(function() {
        run();
    });

    </script>
```

But I think the page will load the php first, it mean `$shim` will be assigned first, then only start executing javascript `function run()`. Thus, `$shim` will be outside the javascript `function run()`, how to use php assign `$shim` into the javascript `function run()`?

I found out what is the actually. The problem is actually I close javascript tag `</script>` before I start php tag `<?php`. Actually I can start php tag directly without closing javascript tag. For example, `<script type="text/javascript"> Java codes here... <?php php codes here.... ?>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function run()
    {
       var paper = Raphael( $('.wrapper')[0], 600, 600 ),

               path = paper.path( Raphael.transformPath(pdefs[useDef].path, pdefs[useDef].transform) )
                           .attr( 'stroke-width', 10 )
                           .attr( 'stroke', 'rgb(80,80,80)' ),

        <?php
         Use mysql get data from database...
         if (condition) {

     $shim = $('<div id=\'shim-1\'><img src=images/buttons/photo.png width=75px height=75px></div>') 
        <?php
         }
        ?>

        }

        $(function() {
            run();
        });
</script>
```

How to call this problem actually? I think this problem is not about php load before javascript...

Comment: PHP runs *before* the web-browser gets the page source. As such the PHP in this question is unwarranted; there is only HTML (with JS). To defer the PHP itself (if indeed such is the 'actual problem'), it must be handled in a *separate* request - XHR, postback with parameter, etc.

Comment: Wild guess: are you looking about sending AJAX requests ?? 
That is PHP loads page, sends to browser > javascript executes on browser > sends ajax request to server (PHP) > which sends data back to javascript, with which you can do as you please.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider what roughly happens:

- The browser (client) sends a request for some URL to the web server over the network.
- The web server runs the PHP script assigned with the URL and generates the  HTML page (including JavaScript
  source, CSS, etc).
- This pages goes over the network into the client.
- The client parses the HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

So JavaScript is executed on the client after PHP has been executed on the server.

Now to your detailed problem, to me it seems you simply want

```js
function run() {

  var paper = Raphael( $('.wrapper')[0], 600, 600 ),
      path = paper.path(
             Raphael.transformPath(pdefs[useDef].path,
                                   pdefs[useDef].transform))
             .attr( 'stroke-width', 10 )
             .attr( 'stroke', 'rgb(80,80,80)' );

  // string broken into three strings to avoid scrolling 
  $shim = $('<div id=\'shim-1\'>' +
          '<img src=images/buttons/photo.png ' + 
          'width=75px height=75px></div>'); 
}
```

Comment: how to use php assign `$shim = $('<div id=\'shim-1\'><img src=images/buttons/photo.png width=75px height=75px></div>')` into the javascript `function run()`?

Comment: @zac1987 It is not clear to me if that is the final JavaScript code that should show up in the generated web page (in that case put that string into the php file) or if PHP has to do something with that statement.

Comment: because i want to make the html div become drag-able. I use jquery-ui raphael `$shim.draggable({ start: function(e){}`

Comment: yes I solved it already. I have edited my post to show the solution. Thanks.